# multiplication in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have these two pandas dataframes and I want to multiply first row to shares with whole 1st column of Log_Return dataframe, similarly the 2nd row of first dataframe with 2nd column of Log_Returns and so on. kindly help me to solve this problem with the help of a loop.

[image]

Comment: you should post the code here.

Comment: I m just asking for idea that how can I do it

Comment: Please see this link on create a [mcve]

Comment: @HussnainAkbar How is this related to `requests`? You tagged the question with that...

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you:

```
i=0
    for j in range(Log_return.shape[1]):
#j chooses the column of Log dataframe
#shape[1] gives number of columns
        for k in range(len(Log_return)):
# k chooses the rows one by one of jth column

             shares.iloc[i,0]*Log_return.iloc[k,j]
#you can multiply and even store the values or do any operations you want 
        i+=1
#i determines the row of shares dataframe
```

Comment: I have tried this code but getting error but no output. Kindly help me out I m stuck here


IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds